# FB return crashes app xcode ios iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

when intergrating FB to my app it comes up and varifies that its connected but when it comes to going back to the app it crashes,

This is the return process from the fb developer page and added it that it comes to my view controller page

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[Ball_GameViewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 

}
```

has an advisory on the line that starts

> return

saying

> warning: 'Ball_GameViewController' may not respond to '+facebook'

any idea am i directing it to the wrong areas.

### Ball_GameViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface Ball_GameViewController : UIViewController <FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate>
{
    Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

- (IBAction)facebookpost;
- (IBAction)start;
- (IBAction)reset;
- (void)countdown;
- (void)scorecount;
- (void)checkTime;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **`Ball_GameViewController`** `@interface` you need to use:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Facebook * facebook;
```

In your **`Ball_GameViewController`** `@implementation` you need to `@synthesize facebook;`

### Update

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    Ball_GameViewController * ballGame = [[Ball_GameViewController alloc] init];

    return [[ballGame facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

Comment: i have #import "FBConnect.h"


@interface Ball_GameViewController : UIViewController <FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate>
{
 Facebook *facebook;'

Comment: and i have @property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

Comment: Then clean your project and try to rebuild it. This is what would cause that warning. Also make sure you have `@synthesize facebook;` in your .m file.